# Adding additional data to a WinForms ListViewItem

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to WinForms and I can't understand how to add my additional data to a `ListViewItem`? I remember that in MFC, I can use `SetItemDataPtr` but how to do this in WinForms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ListViewItem.Tag property to store a reference to any object, the equivalent of SetItemDataPtr().  The Name property can be handy to act as a key in a Dictionary<>.  And the Index property could be useful to index a List<>.  The latter two approaches are the better solutions, you normally want to keep the data separate from the view.

Comment: @Sanja Melnichuk: Index isn't exactly appropriate for storing any arbitrary data in the item, because Index also controls the order of items in the list. Name has some limitations, like not supporting spaces in the name, and not supporting multiple items with the same name. I would strongly recommend deriving a class from ListViewItem, and define your data as members of this item. See my answer below...

Answer (score 6):

The most recommended method would be to create your own class, deriving from `ListViewItem`, and add instances of this class to the `ListView`. This way you can store any data in the items.

This is better than using the `Tag` property, because of several reasons:

- Your item data can be type-safe, and you won't have to cast from Object on each access.
- You can store more than one value.
- It is more correct in terms of object oriented programming.
- You leave the `Tag` property free to be used by potential future extensions.

Comment: Your first bullet is not accurate, you still have to cast from ListViewItem when you retrieve the reference from Items.

Comment: True, but wouldn't you prefer to cast the ListViewItem and then access all its data properties safely, then to cast the Tag property for the data?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked on MSDN for the [ListViewItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.aspx) class? There is a wealth of information there along with samples.

```
            // Create three items and three sets of subitems for each item.
            ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem("item1",0);
            // Place a check mark next to the item.
            item1.Checked = true;
            item1.SubItems.Add("1");
            item1.SubItems.Add("2");
            item1.SubItems.Add("3");
            ListViewItem item2 = new ListViewItem("item2",1);
            item2.SubItems.Add("4");
            item2.SubItems.Add("5");
            item2.SubItems.Add("6");
            ListViewItem item3 = new ListViewItem("item3",0);
            // Place a check mark next to the item.
            item3.Checked = true;
            item3.SubItems.Add("7");
            item3.SubItems.Add("8");
            item3.SubItems.Add("9");
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the way: you need to create your own class, for example, `MyItem` and put you items in `List<MyItem>`. Then use data binding. Class `MyItem` should implement `ToString()` method that returns string will be displayed in ListView.